# vertical scrollbar in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar, bootstrap-table

I want to implement vertical scroll bar for my bootstrap table.

I read many examples and implemented a vertical scroll bar successfully, but the problem is that I am not able to set the width of `td` and `th`.

Here is the code for my table:

```css
/* Student Information */

.box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1180px;
  position: relative;
  border-spacing: 0;
  max-width: 1120px;
  border: 2px solid #7ab643;
}
.box th {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Pro Regular;
  color: #055938;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.box td {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-family: Pro Regular;
  color: #a19b97;
}
.box tr td:first {} .box tr {
  height: 20px;
}
tbody {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12">
  <!-- table starts -->
  <table class="box">
    <caption align="top">Student Information's</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Student Id</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Payments</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="bordergreen">Hitu</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">Bansal</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">9417113388</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">Chandigarh</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">Chand</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">CH</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">25 Oct</td>
        <td class="bordergreen">Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Save</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Up-to-date</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <div class="blue dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <div class="yellow dots"></div>
        </td>
        <td>Hitu</td>
        <td>Bansal</td>
        <td>mhshshsh-01</td>
        <td>hbansal@smartlayer.ca</td>
        <td>9417113388</td>
        <td>Chandigarh</td>
        <td>Chand</td>
        <td>CH</td>
        <td>25 Oct</td>
        <td>Done</td>
        <td>Up-to-date</td>
        <td>Edit</td>

      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <div class="col-lg-12  center"><span class="darkgreen">Messages:</span>  <span class="green">654</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- table finishes -->
```

[Here is the JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/fh37yvjs/)

Help me to add the verticle scroll bar for my table and set its structure.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean horizontal scroll?

Comment: Vertical scroll is fairly simple, just limit the height of .table-responsive class